# Polynomial interpolation to LP

Tags: linear-algebra

How I can convert next program to LP (linear programming) or to get some direction how to do this (references).
The problem is :

> I want to find a polynomial $P$ of degree at most $d$ that $||P(x)-y||_1$ is minimal.
>   Where $x, y$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P$ is vector of $(p(x_1), \ldots, p(x_n))$

Comment: How do you define $\|P(x)-y\|_1$?

Comment: Defination for ||x||$_1$   http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/7/c/c7ca5ac6e49a1020c7ff5902faa3b30c.png  @copper.hat

Comment: That's not really  what I was looking for. Your notation is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the Vandermonde Matrix of $x_1,x_2,...$ then if $z$ is the Vector of polynomial coefficients $z=(a_0,a_1,...)^t$ it is $P(x)=Az$.

For $\textrm{min }||Az-y||_2$ the solution is $z=(A^tA)^{-1}A^ty$.

The problem $\textrm{min }||Az-y||_1$ is equivalent to the LP

minimize $\sum \lambda_i$

subject to

$+Az-I\lambda<=+y$

and

$-Az-I\lambda<=-y$

with $\lambda:=(\lambda_1,...)$

In the following change $||Az-y||$ to $||Ax-b||$

[Here's some matlab code that does polynomial regression](http://pastebin.com/sdk5JM04)

This is the output from the code:

[image: this is output form it]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply.
I'm a newbie in this area, can you please give more detail on how it should be done? a small example could be great also...
i have the below article from which i'm trying to understand this topic but without success.
http://mathscience.kiau.ac.ir/Content/Vol4No2/7.pdf)

Comment: Can you please explain why are you using the Vandermonde matrix and how does the eigenvalues related to the solutions?

Comment: in my case d<n for sure, i just can't understand  how does the eigenvalues playing a role? what are they representing in the LP dfenition?
Thanks a lo for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here is the 'trick' you need. Suppose you wish to solve $\min_{x \in C} \|x\|_1$ where $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then you can rewrite the problem as $\min_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n,x \in C} \{ \alpha_1+\cdots \alpha_n | x_i \leq \alpha_i, -x_i \leq \alpha_i, \forall i\}$.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that if you want to find $P$, this means that $x$ and $y$ are known vectors. If you also know $d$, than your polynomial becomes $p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^d a_k x^k$. You can formulate your linear programming problem as :

$$\min z = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i + n_i$$
subject to
$$ p_i - n_i + p(x_i) - y_i, \forall i=1\dots n$$
$$ 0 \le p_i, d_i < \infty$$
$$ -\infty \le a_k < \infty$$

In this formulation,you can take $p_i$ and $n_i$ as the positive and negative parts of the absolute value. If $p(x_i) - y_i>0$, then $p_i >0$ and $n_i = 0$, and conversly.

Hope this helps.